# In MongoDB how can I retrieve all documents in a collection, one chunk at a time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to process through every entry of a 1TB MonogDB collection, so I was thinking I should be able to do something like

```
const length = db.collection.count()
const iterate = (start = 0, chunkSize = 100000) => {
    const end = start + chunkSize
    db.collection.find({}, start, end).toArray().then(items => {
        // process items
        if (end < length) iterate(end)
        else console.log("all done!")
    })
}
iterate()
```

But obviously `collection.find()` doesn't take range parameters like that. Can someone explain the proper way to do this?

Comment: `db.collection.find({_id: {$gt: last_processed_id}}).limit(100000).sort({_id: 1})`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is `sort` integral, or just to put the list in order? As in, if I dont care what order I process the documents in, as long as I process them all, is `sort` necessary?

Comment: the query relies on documents being sorted by \_id. I \_think\_ it's the default ordering, but with databases it's always good to be explicit.